Does it matter if we do an approximation at the start, middle, or end of this calculation?
Hope my question will become clear with this example. I was doing a statistical mechanics exercise where I was deriving the expected energy for a 2D ideal gas in a circular container from the partition function. The wall potential was given by $K(r-R)^2$ where $K$ is the hardness of the walls, $r$ is the position of a particle, and $R$ is the radius of the container. The point of the exercise was to show that the expressions for the ideal gas in that container, and a general ideal gas become equivalent under the assumption that $\sqrt{K} \gg \sqrt{\frac{k_B T}{R^2}}$. The way I did it was coming up to the expression:
$$
-\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} \left( \ln \left( \frac{1}{N! \lambda^{2N}} \right) 
+ N \ln \left( \pi R^2 + \frac{\pi}{\beta K} + \pi R \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\beta K}} \right) \right) 
\approx -\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} \left( \ln \left( \frac{1}{N! \lambda^{2N}} \right) 
+ N \ln \left( \pi R^2 \right) \right)= Nk_B T
$$
Where I basically approximated the expression inside of the second logarithm before differentiating with respect to $\beta$. However, what the solution proposal did, was first evaluate the expression exactly, and then rearrange it such that we can use the inequality to approximate the result. Now obviously both of the approaches result in the same final result, but I wonder if I just got lucky here? My point is, does it matter if I use a given inequality of the form $A\gg B$ before doing full calculations, or at the end? Or any other approximation like Striling's for factorials inside of logarithms for example.

Basically you need to know what you are tossing away.  Only then can you tell if you are doing the approximation consistently.  Since you mention Sterling's approximation, head over to dlmf and look up the asymptotic expansion of gamma function for an illustration.
If you have some leading non-analytic terms, make sure to keep them.  And then usually you just have a series of some (hopefully) small parameter.  You decide where to truncate, make sure you always keep terms at high enough order, and it shouldn't matter when you do the truncation in the calculation.
